# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.jockey' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error message and I have not found the solution

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   (
SELECT  
count(jockey) AS total 
FROM p_mu.cachedate
GROUP BY entraineur
) t 
WHERE t.jockey IN (SELECT jockey FROM p_mu.select_course_chev);
```

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't.jockey' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

I searched everywhere on the site but I did not find the solution

Comment: Could you share the structure of your tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Your outer query is selecting `jockey`, but it is not returned by the subquery.

It is quite unclear what you actually want to do, so it is not possible to provide further assistance.